# SQL bind value/param into prepared statement not working

Tags: php, sql

I have tried searching and cannot find any help on this issue, either due to a lack of experience or understanding on my part---I'm not a very experienced programmer.

I am in the process of creating a simple web-form that queries an SQLite database and returns all rows based on two dates. The today's date and todays dates + an integer which represents the number of days in the future. All dates in the database are stored as text formatted: `YYYY-MM-DD`. I am using PHP on the server.

I have it working like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM walk WHERE walk_date BETWEEN strftime(date('now')) AND strftime(date('now', '" . webdata['int_passed_from_form'] . " day'))";
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
$result = $stmt->execute()
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out why I cannot bind the integer to the prepared statement like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM walk WHERE walk_date BETWEEN strftime(date('now')) AND strftime(date('now', ':date day'))";
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue(':date', $webdata['int_passed_from_form'], SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$result = $stmt->execute()
```

Or:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM walk WHERE walk_date BETWEEN strftime(date('now')) AND strftime(date('now', ':date day'))";
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue(':date', $webdata['int_passed_from_form'], SQLITE3_TEXT);
$result = $stmt->execute()
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been banging my head against a wall all day. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `':date'` and concat `day` on the variable value.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I knew it would be simple but I didn't realise how annoying it would be to find out! I am an idiot! Thank you.

Comment: @sylph - I have to disagree with your. This does not make you an idiot. Most developers (even experienced ones) get's stuck on silly mistakes from time to time. :-)